# PHP - session_start() headers are already sent

Tags: php, html

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Вот код документа:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset ($_POST['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Среда программирования - Dreamweaver CS6. Сохраняю документ в кодировке UTF-8. Что насчёт какой-то `UTF8-BOM` - не знаю, просто UTF-8. Доступ к настройкам PHP (файл php.ini) имеется. В интернете решение своей проблемы не нашёл. Подскажите, как исправить эту ошибку.

Comment: Так в этом и проблема. Надо сохранять файл в кодировке `UTF8 без BOM`

Comment: Там просто UTF-8 либо любая другая. В блокноте тоже самое. Там нет никакой UTF8 без BOM или с BOM.

Comment: Открывай `notepad++` и меняй

Comment: А еще лучше закрой навсегда программу `Dreamweaver`  и начни использовать нормальную `IDE` для разработки, к примеру `PHPStorm` А этим дримвивером уже не пользуются уважающие себя разрабы)

Comment: Скачайте блокнот `AkelPad`, при сохранении документа как... есть возможность сохранить в `UTF без BOM`.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что свой файл `PHP` вы можете создать в кодировке `UTF-8`, и некоторые редакторы кода в начало файла запишут дополнительный специальный символ, идентификатор **UTF-8 (BOM - byte order mark)**. В редакторе он отображаться не будет, а вот сервер, который будет обрабатывать этот файл, может его принять просто за одиночный символ и вывести его сразу после заголовков. Этот символ тоже может вообще никак не отобразиться в браузере, но если посмотреть исходный код страницы, можно увидеть дополнительный отступ или знак `"?"` перед основным содержимым (обычно перед тегом `BODY`) Соответственно, если такой символ выводится, а в файле есть функция Header(), то это и приведет к появлению ошибки **Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by**. Увидеть этот символ, в виде знака ?, квадратика или пробела можно, открыв файл в обычном блокноте. Чтобы избавиться от этой проблемы, в настройках своего редактора PHP найдите и отключите вставку этого идентификатора.

Со всеми случаями когда может появляется данная ошибка можно ознакомится в данном документе: http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/

Comment: Спасибо. P.S. Это я задал вопрос. Не с того аккаунта случайно залез).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить строку session_start(); и проверьте еще раз. Если в php.ini стоит автоматическое создание сессии, то эта строка лишняя.