# Как вернуться на страницу если на ней есть вывод?

Tags: php, javascript, redbeanphp

Привет ребят! Столкнулся с такой траблой и чот не могу найти решение. В общем есть страница users.php, нажав на ней submit [удалить], action стартует скрипт написанный на странице - del.php, там же есть SQL запрос в БД перед условием:

```
    <?php require_once 'db.php' ?>
    <?php require_once 'libs/libs_users.php' ?>
    <?php
    if (empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        header("Location: users.php");
        exit();
    }
        $а = show(); // *переменная = функция (redbeanphp запрос на вывод всего содержимого)
        if (!empty($_POST['checkbox']))
            foreach ($a as $val){
                if (in_array($val['id'], $_POST['checkbox'])) {
                    /*var_dump($val['id']);*/
                    $a = R::trash('users', $val['id']); // redbeanphp удаление
        header("Location: users.php");
        exit();
                }
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Где ты пишешь этот код? `header("Location: user.php");`

Comment: До этого кода не должно быть ни какого вывода типа `echo, print_r, var_dum` Или какие то `html` куски кода.

Comment: `собственно запрос в БД засчитан как вывод` это фантастика! Смотрите в своих файлах лишние строки/пробелы до `<?php` или метки BOM.

Comment: Приведите свой `del.php` полностью.

Comment: @Visman там скорее несколько секций `<?php` между которыми `\n`

Comment: Ребят без обид, читаем, вникаем, коментим. Хидер пишу в условии, которое написано выше, кодировка без БОМ, вывод есть перед хидером В КАЧЕСТВЕ sql запроса, собственно в этом и вопрос, ...есть ли возможность и как?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php супер функция решающая любые проблемы с выводом ;)

Comment: Visman СПАСИБО!  Я даже сам себя "наругал" за глупость, ведь на неделе смотрел её. Всё работает!

Comment: @CyberJo без обид, но лучше бы сами  разобрались, о чем вам в комментах написали. закрыв косяк `ob_start` вы свою глупость просто на два помножили и все.

Comment: @CyberJo не много ли гонору то? Тебе не только я написал, искать лишние строки пробелы. Полный код как раз и нужен, для того чтобы тебя носом ткнуть, где они находятся. Твои отдельные две части кода бесполезны для поиска ошибки, когда они написаны отдельно. После того как ты возомнил себя самым умным и отправил всех подальше, тебе скормили `ob_start`. Это решение тебе безусловно поможет, но в данном вопросе это говнокод. Дали тебе его именно по этой причине, ибо твой уровень разработчика в целом ясен,  разбираться в причинах ты не хочешь.

Comment: @teran. Заданный вопрос решен. У тебя есть другое решение? Напиши и оценим твой интеллект, пока я вижу только бла-бла.

Comment: Заметь кстати, что `ob_start` ты написал в начале блока и код стал работать, отсюда очевидно следует, что запрос к БД ничего в буфер вывода не заносит и раньше тоже не заносил. Хотя кое-кто чуть ли не с пеной у рта доказывал, что во всем виновато `R::trash()`, а мы тут все дураки

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить у тешащего перед студентом свое ЧСВ разработчика, вникнувшего в суть вопроса и разобравшегося в коде, а при чем тут запрос R::trash() = удаление, стоящее в самом конце кода?! Я говорил про функцию show(), которая вызывается переменной $a, которая в себе содержит запрос на вывод содержимого таблицы а-ля SELECT FROM * table. Опять же, есть решение? Выдай! Не надо голословности я сюда пришел не за теорией.

Comment: если в `_POST` не передано `checkbox`  (то есть выполняется первый `if`), то опять не работает?

Comment: Закидали какахами лол) @teran, просил код ВЕСЬ - прикреплен! Повторюсь, пробелов нет, кодировка без BOM. Почему работает так я не знаю. без функции ob_start, выглядит так: http://i96.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0613/aa/6d3099946fbe7c94c32f12a8c2c1f9aa.jpg

Comment: Стыдно признавать ошибку, но я нашел её, я даже в эту сторону не подумал бы. Спасибо teran, что заставил разозлиться и включить голову) Ошибка была детской, 13 строка, вывод var_dump... ппц.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP - session\_start() headers are already sent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478169/php-session-start-headers-are-already-sent)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте ajax для этих целей (как вариант), тогда ничего перегружать не придется:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  data: $("form").serialize,
  url: "del.php",
  success: function(data){
    if(data=="ERROR"){
      //показывать ошибку на странице или в модальном окне
    }else{
      //обновлять data на странице, если требуется
    }
  }
});
```

Надеюсь, логику не напутал.

Comment: типа - когда не можешь понять в чем дело - напиши костыль?

Comment: В тегах указан `javascript`, как один из вариантов, вполне себе решение, думаю. Из-за чего сарказм?

Comment: Спасибо за ваше время и ответ! Ваш вариант я не проверял т.к. выше есть совершенно простое решение, по этому не вижу смысла мудрить, тем более на онклик уже стоит функция.

Answer (score 1):

После закрывающего php тега можно дописать

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
location = "URL"
</script>
```

Comment: Супер! (и еще 9 символов)

Comment: весьма  изящный ход!

Comment: @teran, а у меня в комментарии был сарказм ;)

Comment: @Visman в чем я вас и поддержал :) сюда бы не помешали смайлики фейспалма :D

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в выводе перед header, var_dump.